# Should I split user stories on Frontend vs Backend tasks?

Tags: agile, scrum

While applying Scrum, the product backlog items are users stories. I have created a sample story on TFS as follows:

> As a user, I can signup to system.

I then created the following tasks:

1. A login form should be prepared.
2. User should fill all fields on the form.
3. User should type a valid formatted email.
4. User passwords match between.
5. If user fills the form successfully, send verification email.

Some of the tasks are frontend (HTML, CSS, etc) and some are backend (send email, etc).

1. Should I separate the frontend and backend tasks one to another? And should I separate them into different User Stories?
2. Can the tasks be implemented by different developers?

Comment: When you say, "Can user story tasks do by multiple users?" do you mean, "can the tasks be implemented by different developers?"

Comment: Just because this is about a development methodology, doesn't make it opinion based. Scrum has a Scrum way to do things which is not about my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. Agile focuses on delivering working code to the customer. Without each part implemented the code written offers no value. Unless the tasks can be shown to offer independent value, then they should be kept together.
2. Yes the different parts can be implemented by different people. You need to make sure they coordinate appropriately so that the requested feature as works a whole.

Comment: Your answer is very explanatory, thanks. I mean that, agile focuses proper planning but does not care coding the frontend and backend. is true?

Comment: Agile is a set of values and principles for developing software. It doesn't mandate anything about frontend/backend code.

Comment: If a backend task means an API endpoint, then I think it has independent value since it can be requested independently. In this case, is it justified to make this backend task a single story? If yes, then the next story will be the frontend UI that use this API endpoint. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's all well and good honouring the communication point in Agile and expecting/advising devs to talk to one another, but if you wanted a certain degree of autonomy in terms of the relevant team member picking up the right ticket at the right time, you need to have a workflow that appreciates the componentised nature of product development.

In my head that sounds right...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please specify what you mean by *that* in your last sentence?

Comment: My statement! It was more of a thinking aloud statement as I'm struggling with managing how requirements flow across our board.